# Changing titles on buttons with custom NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need to change the title of a button, but the title of the button needs to change depending on the index of the NSArray I choose. How do I do that?

Code:

```
   NSArray * answerChoiceArray1 = @[@"1492", @"13", @"Spain", @"1678", @"1775", @"1848", @"1899", @"1908", @"1928", @"1999", @"12,000s BCE", @"Caral", @"Caral", @"Nazca", @"France and Germany", @"Netherlands", @"1635", @"1883", @"1498", @"1917", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @""];
    NSArray * answerChoiceArray2 = @[@"1675", @"15", @"France", @"1733", @"1809", @"1910", @"1908", @"1929", @"1935", @"2001", @"8,000s BCE", @"Chibchas", @"Chavin", @"Wari", @"Austria and Italy", @"Spain", @"1789", @"1912", @"1532", @"1906", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @""];
    NSArray * answerChoiceArray3 = @[@"1776", @"27", @"Austria", @"1789", @"1852", @"1920", @"1917", @"1933", @"1939", @"2003", @"6,000s BCE", @"Canaris", @"Inca", @"Inca", @"Spain and Portugal", @"France", @"1822", @"1966", @"1617", @"1816", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @""];
    NSArray * answerChoiceArray4 = @[@"1783", @"50", @"Italy", @"1806", @"1861", @"1939", @"1921", @"1939", @"1941", @"2005", @"4,000s BCE", @"Chavin", @"Moche", @"Moche", @"Sweden and Germany", @"Portugal", @"1912", @"1973”", @"1769", @"1888", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @""];


    currentQuestion.answerChoice1 = [answerChoiceArray1 objectAtIndex:_generateQuestionArrayIndex];

    currentQuestion.answerChoice2 = [answerChoiceArray2 objectAtIndex:_generateQuestionArrayIndex];

    currentQuestion.answerChoice3 = [answerChoiceArray3 objectAtIndex:_generateQuestionArrayIndex];

    currentQuestion.answerChoice4 = [answerChoiceArray4 objectAtIndex:_generateQuestionArrayIndex];


    [_displayAnswerChoice1 setTitle:@"%@", currentQuestion.answerChoice1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use variable name (if it is a string)

//if it is a string

```
[_displayAnswerChoice1 setTitle : currentQuestion.answerChoice1 forState : UIControlStateNormal];
```

//If you want to add prefix, suffix or any other formatted text then use `stringWithFormat`

```
[_displayAnswerChoice1 setTitle : [NSString stringWithFormat : @"%@", currentQuestion.answerChoice1] forState : UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to set the value directly, then you don't need the @"%@".

```
[_displayAnswerChoice1 setTitle:currentQuestion.answerChoice1
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```